# Does it make sense for a reduced parameter space to improve SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have seen the following claim in a paper:

There are four real variables $a,b,c,d$ and a class label $y$. A support vector machine (SVM) was incapable of determining $y$ from $a,b,c,d$ without error, but it *was* able to do it based on the reduced parameter space $a/b, c, d$ (i.e. $a$ divided by $b$ as one of the features).

I would think that if $a/b$ were such a valuable feature, SVM would be able to find it. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVM does not "find features", the features are pre-specified (either directly, or via a kernel function). Moreover, SVM is a linear technique, while your "reduction" introduces a new *nonlinear* feature $a/b$. So the result is perfectly sensible.